# How to specify Dotfuscator's "inclusion/exclusion lists" on the command line?

Tags: msbuild, .net-3.5, dotfuscator

I am calling *Dotfuscator* in the Post-build event and want it to encrypt string literals in my assembly. Unfortunately, it can only be done by specifying a so-called String encryption inclusion list. Is there a way to provide it via the command-line interface? I could do it in the *Dotfuscator*'s config file, but that would require the hard-coding of a path, which I prefer to avoid. The *Dotfuscator* executable's location is on the `PATH` environment variable.

I would have used *MSBuild*'s `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` property to locate the config file relative to this path, but it is not supported in *.NET 3.5*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following sectio to *Dotfuscator*'s `config.xml` fixed the problem:

```
<renaming>
  <excludelist>
    <type name=".*" regex="true" excludetype="true">
      <customattribute name=".*Generated.*" regex="true"/>
    </type>
  </excludelist>
</renaming>
```